# Move Sprite gradually up (Jump)

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone

Im having a problem making a sprite Jump on my XNA Game for Windows Phone when I touch the screen.

I have the following code at the moment.

```
foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
{
    if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed))
    {
        rectangleSprite.Y -= 55;
     }
}
```

NOTE:

```
rectangleSprite = new Rectangle((int)newPosition.X, (int)newPosition.Y, textureSprite.Width, textureSprite.Height)
```

MY code makes the sprite move to the new position. That works as a jump, but I want it to be more gradually, so you can see it jumping.

Comment: Take a look at this blog: [The Wizard - Part 2
Making a Sprite Jump](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thewizardjumping/thewizardjumping.shtml)

Comment: Do I really need enum to do this? :S Didnt understand very well that tutorial.

Comment: your code didn't jump sprite, but move it for 55 pixels. you have to create a code that will move sprite from current location to location+55px and then back down. there are hundred different ways how to achieve this. fixed speed, using sinus function, using gravity with velocity...

Comment: Im close to that, I have this so it goes back down.

rectangleSprite.Y += (int)(velocity.Y * timeelapsed);

So to go up I need: 

rectangleFish.Y -= (int)(velocity.Y * timeelapsed);

until my desired position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your character jump better you have to add velocity to your code, and put your jump function in the `update()` method.

You need to add gravity.
In your update you can add something like this.

```
float i = 1; velocity.Y += 0.15f * i;
```

Reminder: ^this only works if you set your code so, that you character can't go below the surface it stands on.
Because it will make it go down every time the code calls the `update()` method.

Then if you want, make a `boolean`, to check if you player has jumped.

```
foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
{
    if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed && hasJumped == false))
    {
        position.Y -=10f;
        veloctity.Y -= 5f;
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Do not forget to update the position of your character.
The position:

```
Vector2 position;
```

the update code:

```
position = position + velocity;
```

**Some things u might want to read/watch:**

Like *scheien* said:
http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thewizardjumping/thewizardjumping.shtml

Little video that maybe helps with explaining.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLxIShw-7ac

**I'm also on this site to learn so any suggestions or edits are welcome!**

Comment: Why we use another variable to store only the value 1?
We could simple use velocity.Y += 0.15f.

Im trying that, but it keeps "no jumping". It just re moving the sprite from one location to another :S

Comment: I took it out of a game of mine, It's for another function, you don't have to use the value 1 xD.
Please watch the video tut it will explain exactly how to do it.

Comment: Did u solve your problem and if this had the answer would you like to accept it please?

Comment: This solution didnt solve my problem because im using rectangles and it seems diferent. Anyway this was a good help.

Comment: I'm also using rectangles in my project but, you have to make your rectangle so it follows your player.
Like this: `playerRec = new Rectangle((int)player.position.X, (int)player.position.Y, player.width, player.height);` Please try to get more knowledge on how XNA works. You are on the right way :)

Comment: It seems rectangle moves faster than with texture. I think its because those int values that retangle uses (int, int). With Vector2 we can use float values. Anyways i accomplished what i wanted. Thank you for your help.